# How do I add two numbers and display the result by using <h:outputText>?

Tags: jsf

I was wondering how do I add two numbers, in this case `Car.number.Audi` and `Car.number.VW` using `<h:outputText>` to display the result:

```html
 #{Car.number.Audi} = 3
 #{Car.number.VW} = 2

 <div>
     <h:outputText styleClass="Car-Column" 
                   value="#{Car.number.Audi} + #{Car.number.VW}"/>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you do it, what will be rendered will be `3+2` as a plain String.

In order to apply the addition, you have to do:

```
value="#{Car.number.Audi + Car.number.VW}"
```